# can we use zend library in our own php application

Tags: php, zend-framework

is it compulsory to use zend framework structure for using zend library or we can use zend library in our own php application...

Comment: yes you can, which zend library you are referring to. ZF 1 or ZF2

Answer (score 2):

Three steps to using the ZF (assuming ZF1) library in your own app without the entire ZF MVC stack.

1. **Set the include path**

   Make sure that the `Zend` library folder is on your php `include_path`.
2. **Load your class**

   You could just include each class file before you use it:

   ```
   require_once 'Zend/Validate/EmailAddress.php';
   $validator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();
   ```

   But it's a pain to do it that way. Typically, it's better to using the autoloader. The easiest way is something like (early in your bootstrap process, perhaps in a `common.php` file, YMMV):

   ```
   require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
   Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
   ```

   Once this is done, you can instantiate/reference on-demand:

   ```
   $validator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();
   ```
3. **Instantiate/Reference**

   ```
   $validator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();
   echo $validator->isValid('test@example.com') ? "Cool" : "Fail";
   ```